# Using different classes for EntityFramework Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, attributes

I have a scenario where I have two different classes which essentially represent the same object.

I have a ContactPerson and ContactDetails. The ContactPerson is an EntityObject and ContactDetails inherits from ContactPerson but adds its own attributes. Essentially I want ContactDetails to inherit all of ContactPerson's properties, add its attributes then be insertable into the EF model.

**Attempt**

I made all of ContactPerson's properties virtual, then EF interpreted this as change tracking. I've also tried making an abstract class and then ContactPerson inherits from there. So what is the best approach to have a scenario like this but avoid boilerplate code.

```
public class ContactPerson
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

public class ContactDetails : ContactPerson
{
    [ElementText("textView_4")]
    public override string Title { get; set; }

    [ElementText("textView_6")]
    public override string AcademicTitle { get; set; }

    [ElementText("firstname")]
    public override string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ElementText("lastname")]
    public override string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:**

For a bit more background information, ContactDetails comes from a different datasource and both these objects reside in different projects. I'm using this approach to scrape a website and insert the information into EF.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Interface instead of using ContactPerson as a base class if you will override all its properties in ContactDetails.

```
public interface IContact
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

Then implement it on your two classes :

```
public class ContactPerson : IContact
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

public class ContactDetails : IContact
{
    [ElementText("textView_4")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ElementText("textView_6")]
    public string AcademicTitle { get; set; }

    [ElementText("firstname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ElementText("lastname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

That will provide you compile time checks that all your properties are implemented on each class.

You can then use tools like Auto Mapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) to easily transfer your data between two instances of your IContact.